# How to configure vim/neovim to locate include (headers) with Makefile?

Tags: vim, makefile, neovim, vim-plugin

I'm searching an option or a plugin to vim that will configure vim to use my Makefile to find the paths to the files that I include.
Example (in cpp file):

```cpp
#include "my_header.hpp"
int main()
{
    HeaderFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

In a makefile in the same directory there will be all the compile flags and the include paths to the relevant files that I include.

I can do manually :set path+=<path_to_my_header.hpp>

I've read the path documantation, consult few vim users and searched for plugins and configurations but didn't find anything appropriate.

I'm searching for an automatic solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I have searched for plugins or ways to configure the deafults. I've only found mannual soltutions like writing explicit path or expanding set path . I'm just starting to know vim, and while the make commands works fine and I can run and compile the program, I see "file not found" errors. Edited the question and added what I tried

Comment: Can we see the relevant part of your `Makefile`?

Comment: It's a bit complicated, I'm adding a link for the full Makefile: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mzgAFAN6P203wyBaBVwc3-tud9c2or2_/view?usp=share_link)  
Inside you can find these lines:    
IDIR = $(PWD)include/    


$(VAR).out: $(OBJ) 
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ODIR)$(VAR)_test.o $(LDIR)$(VAR).so -I$(IDIR) -o$(TARGET) -lm  


CFLAGS = -std=c++20 -fdiagnostics-color=always -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -DNDEBUG -O3 -Wextra -g -pthread -Wl,-rpath,PWD